# What was the exact vote of the UN Human Rights Council on Xinjiang?

Tags: china, united-nations, human-rights, uyghurs

There just was a vote in the 47-member U.N. Human Rights Council, and it is really easy to find quotes like this:

> The 47-member U.N. Human Rights Council has rejected a resolution to hold a debate next year on  alleged human rights abuses in Xinjiang by a narrow margin of 19 votes against, 17 in favor and 11 abstentions.

But I would really like details of the exact vote of all 47 members, and I can't find it.

Can anyone find exactly who voted for each side? Bonus points for tips on how to google for votes in the UN system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A decent, easily accessible source for up-to-the-minute votes from the UN HRC is their twitter account, which [tweeted full results of the vote](https://twitter.com/UN_HRC/status/1578003299827171330).

> **For:** Czechia, Finland, France, Germany, Honduras, Japan, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Marshall Islands, Montenegro, Netherlands, Paraguay, Poland, Republic of Korea, Somalia, United Kingdom, United States.
>
> **Against:** Bolivia, Cameroon, China, Côte d’Ivoire, Cuba, Eritrea, Gabon, Indonesia, Kazakhstan, Mauritania, Namibia, Nepal, Pakistan, Qatar, Senegal, Sudan, UAE, Uzbekistan, Venezuela.
>
> **Abstaining:** Argentina, Armenia, Benin, Brazil, Gambia, India, Libya, Malawi, Malaysia, Mexico, Ukraine.

For a more official, in-depth source, the full list of decisions and resolutions for the Council’s 51st session may be found on the OHCHR’s website [here](https://hrcmeetings.ohchr.org/HRCSessions/RegularSessions/51/Pages/resolutions.aspx). Details on this resolution in particular may be found [here](https://hrcmeetings.ohchr.org/HRCSessions/RegularSessions/51/DL_Resolutions/Forms/ResolutionDS/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=21&FolderCTID=0x0120D520005A4381ABFFD48642897E02288D058A22001B07C878276D3B4E9F9B79D83234987E&List=f97dc3a9-0289-4520-a186-336c6365e37d&RootFolder=%2FHRCSessions%2FRegularSessions%2F51%2FDL%5FResolutions%2FA%5FHRC%5F51%5FL%2E6&RecSrc=%2FHRCSessions%2FRegularSessions%2F51%2FDL%5FResolutions%2FA%5FHRC%5F51%5FL%2E6).